# Check if object is child of a class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, typeof

I want to know if a certain object is of a certain Type that is a child class. I've got 3 classes: `Participant`, `Human : Participant` and `AI : Participant` where the instances are implemented as followed:

```
Participant player1 = new Human();

Participant player2 = new AI();
```

I've got these players in an `participants[2]{ player1, player2 };` and a variable `currentParticipant` that keeps track of who's turn it is.

I want to check if `participants[currentParticipant]` is of type `AI`, which I have done like this:

```
private void CheckParticipantsTurn(int currentParticipant)
    {
        if(participants[currentParticipant] is AI)
        {
            participants[currentParticipant].AiMove(); //currently empty
            MessageBox.Show("Ai moved");
        }
        ChangeCurrentParticipant(currentParticipant); //switches current participant
    }
```

However, it never seems to see `player2` as an AI - it sees it as a Participant.

**Question:**

How do I check if player2 is of type AI, instead of Participant?

Comment: `player2 is AI`

Comment: What value you have for AI in `currentParticipant`? Did you debug the code and check if you are having correct values in variables and array.

Comment: Impossible. Please post a complete example.

Comment: To my knowledge, it doesn't really matter what AI contrains. It also didn't amtter what  `currentParticipant` was, I just couldn't "find" the class/type of the current player, the only thing that worked was `is Player`, which defeats the purpose of the check in general.

I just needed to check if `player2` was of type AI, nothing more. It works using @Hitesh P 's method (check answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if ( participants[currentParticipant].GetType() == typeof(AI) )